# How to define Maven pom.xml for using org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector

Tags: java, maven, ssl

I want to set SSL (org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector) for jetty server, and the maven project is using jetty version 9.3.20.v20170531.

After doing some research, I found that jetty-server 8.1.18.v20150929 has the "org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector" class.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>8.1.18.v20150929</version>
</dependency>
```

But jetty-server 9.3.20.v20170531 doesn't have that class.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>9.3.20.v20170531</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't understand why jetty-server 9.3.20.v20170531 is missing that class, is it moved to other artifactId?

Is it possible to use jetty-server 9.3.20.v20170531 for implementing the "org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector" for setting up SSL on jetty server?

**Update:**

For using jetty.xml to define the connector, how to migrate the connector inside this jetty.xml to the mentioned "new way"?

```
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
            <Arg>
                <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl.SslContextFactory">
                    <Set name="keyStore">/etc/keystore.jks</Set>
                    <Set name="keyStorePassword">Password</Set>
                    <Set name="keyManagerPassword">Password</Set>
                    <Set name="trustStore">/etc/truststore.jks</Set>
                    <Set name="trustStorePassword">Password</Set>
                </New>
            </Arg>
            <Set name="host">example.com</Set>
            <Set name="port">12345</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the jetty-server was cleaned up a bit and these Connectors are not used anymore. Maybe you can have a look at the following post to find a way on how to migrate your code to the new way of work: https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jetty-dev/msg01952.html

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. For using jetty.xml to define the connector, how to migrate the connector inside this jetty.xml to the mentioned "new way"? Please see the updated content.